# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error for array of json objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am decoding the array of json objects into html lists . i have tried with some demo it worked but when i deal with this array of json this gives error as :  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). what is i am missing ?

```
    <?php
$json_string = '{"error":false,"data":[{"jb_product_category_id":"1","jb_product_category_name":"Mother","jb_product_category_prefix":"jbpm","jb_product_category_delete_status":"0","jb_product_category_created_on":"1501500876531","jb_product_category_updated_on":"1501500876531","subCategory1":[{"jb_product_subcategory1_1_id":"1","jb_product_subcategory1_2_category_id":"1","jb_product_subcategory1_3_name":"Cloths","jb_product_subcategory1_4_delete_status":"0","jb_product_subcategory1_5_created_on":"1501563015164","jb_product_subcategory1_6_updated_on":"1501563015164","subCategory2":[{"jb_product_subcategory2_1_id":"1","jb_product_subcategory2_2_category_id":"1","jb_product_subcategory2_3_subcategory1_id":"1","jb_product_subcategory2_4_name":"Pregnancy wear","jb_product_subcategory2_5_delete_status":"0","jb_product_subcategory2_6_created_on":"1501574226464","jb_product_subcategory2_7_updated_on":"1501574226464"}]}]},{"jb_product_category_id":"2","jb_product_category_name":"Child Wear","jb_product_category_prefix":"jbpc","jb_product_category_delete_status":"0","jb_product_category_created_on":"1502429483534","jb_product_category_updated_on":"1502429483534","subCategory1":[{"jb_product_subcategory1_1_id":"2","jb_product_subcategory1_2_category_id":"2","jb_product_subcategory1_3_name":"Girls","jb_product_subcategory1_4_delete_status":"0","jb_product_subcategory1_5_created_on":"1502429606169","jb_product_subcategory1_6_updated_on":"1502429606169","subCategory2":[{"jb_product_subcategory2_1_id":"2","jb_product_subcategory2_2_category_id":"2","jb_product_subcategory2_3_subcategory1_id":"2","jb_product_subcategory2_4_name":"Western","jb_product_subcategory2_5_delete_status":"0","jb_product_subcategory2_6_created_on":"1502429794573","jb_product_subcategory2_7_updated_on":"1502429794573"}]},{"jb_product_subcategory1_1_id":"3","jb_product_subcategory1_2_category_id":"2","jb_product_subcategory1_3_name":"Boys","jb_product_subcategory1_4_delete_status":"0","jb_product_subcategory1_5_created_on":"1505105190176","jb_product_subcategory1_6_updated_on":"1505105190176","subCategory2":[]}]}]}';

    $array = json_decode($json_string, true);
    function build_list($array) {
    $list = '<ul>';
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $index) {
     if(is_array($index)) {
       $list .= build_list($index);
        } else {
       $list .= "<li>$index</li>";
      }
     }
    }

      $list .= '</ul>';
    return $list;
        }

echo build_list($array);
    ?>
```

Comment: $key is used two times, can you plz use different variable name. Also check if your are getting proper array after decoading. Just to confirm

Comment: i make this as foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                            foreach($value as $key1 => $index) {  but no change.

Comment: Not sure, but can you please confirm that $value is also an array, or just print and check if you are getitng array of not foreach variable.

Comment: how do i only show specific value to list that i want ? eg . Mother , cloths ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use only one foreach, the nested one seems useless :

```
foreach($array as $key => $index) {
  if(is_array($index)) {
  /* ... */
```

Comment: bravo !! it worked . how do i only show specific value to list that i want ? eg . Mother  , cloths ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition to check if `$value` is a valid array or not. This way it will not process `$value` if it's not an array and warnings will go away.

```
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        continue;
    }
```

Use this condition inside `foreach` before the looping `$array`.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach($value as $k => $index) {
     if(is_array($index)) {
       $list .= build_list($index);
        } else {
       $list .= "<li>$index</li>";
      }
    }
}
```

Ideone link : [Code](https://ideone.com/8XSCjk)